# Google sheets onEdit stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone please help with, for some reason out of nowhere the "onEdit" function stopped working for me.
Yesterday everything worked perfectly fine and I checked the authorization but for some reason the following `onEdit()` script no longer works for me?
I also get the "Cannot read property "range" from undefined" error.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  insertRow(e);
  timeStamp(e);
}

function insertRow(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if(sh.getName()!="Test")return;
  var colIValue=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,9).getValue();
  var colHValue=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8).getValue();
  if (colHValue=="Yes" & e.range.getColumn()==9 & colIValue==true){
    sh.insertRowsAfter(e.range.rowStart, Number(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).getValue())-1);
  }
}

function timeStamp(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Test"){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart<7) {
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,7,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(ts);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you edit more than 2 ranges at a time, onEdit will simply ignore those changes, so any logic applied inside of onEdit should be assuming you will literally not execute onEdit half the time.

Comment: What would be the best solution to fix this issue?

Comment: When you apply your function's logic you just need to assume that you missed a bunch of onEdit's which means you have to look at the entire column or row, it is just very specific to your situation, let's say you want to timestamp, well now you need to somehow check if something already has a timestamp or not you might have to enter 3 timestamps at once.

Comment: Sorry about this I'm really a beginner, how do I do this? The weird problem for me now is that not even the insert Row doesn't work anymore and I have removed the timeStamp function just to check if it works.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want the behavior to be, which rows, columns, etc. Also are you ok with dragging down formulas or do you plan on entering infinite data this way?

Comment: Well I want to insert a number of rows based on the number-1 found in column D (ex: if D2 = 3 I want to insert 3-1 rows below it) if Column H == "Yes" and Column == True (I want for the trigger to be the checkbox in column I), I want to make sure that the insert row triggers only when the checkbox === True not if I update any of the cells around it. Also I want to register a time stamp once in column G once multiple data is added in the spreadsheet in the Range of An:Fn, any update that it's done after column G I don't want the onUpdate to register it.

Comment: Does Cooper's answer resolve your question?

Comment: Also, what line is the `Cannot read property "range" from undefined` error appearing on?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test Cooper's answer, I will follow up as soon as I do. @RafaGuillermo, the Cannot read property range error appears on var range = e.range in the insertRow function.

Comment: Neither of these are used in insertRow  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = e.range;`but `sh` is and it's not defined.  You need to spend some time learning how to debug code.

Comment: Thank you Cooper! Yes... I'm trying to learn as I code. I'm a complete beginner and the only method I could find that works best for me to learn is having a project in mind.  I tried many times finishing entier tutorials but they never stuck with me, it seams going through a project and hitting my head on walls, encountering different issues, somehow is a best learning practice for me lol. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Flag1');
  insertRow(e);
  timeStamp(e);
}

function insertRow(e) {
  //e.source.toast('flag2');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if(sh.getName()!="Test")return;
  var colIValue=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,9).getValue();
  var colHValue=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8).getValue();
  //the next line is always false unless you have a checkbox in column9 and you set it up with a custom value of 'yes' for true.
  if (colHValue=="Yes" && e.range.columnStart==9 && colIValue==true){
    sh.insertRowsAfter(e.range.rowStart, Number(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).getValue())-1);
  }
}

function timeStamp(e) {
  //e.source.toast('flag3');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Test"){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart<7) {
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,7,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,1).setValue(ts);
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy New Year @Cooper and all the best! I tried the above code and it's working perfectly as it did before. May I ask what was missing in the code I posted that made it to stop working?